# htmx page send no data

Tags: cgi, htmx

Just discovery HTMX. Create a simple page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
HTMX - elementary example
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/htmx.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/HTMX/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

<button hx-post="cgi-bin/answer.cmd" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#answer-div">
    Retrieve answer!
</button>

<div id="answer-div">
    DIR output shuld be displayed here
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when click to button (no data sended to server - tested by wireshark). On developer console F12 is displayed error `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` What could be wrong?

Comment: htmx requires html as response not cgi script, hence the error I presume. You should instead process your script internally on server side and return html instead.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you add the exact response content you're getting for above example? Thanks.

Comment: Index.html page is loaded to browser, press F12 and see error. No button was clicked, no request was sent [confirmed by wireshark]. Just html page load cause this error. IMHO it has nothing with CGI script, it happens before the script is employed to game.

Comment: Are you sure that the static file is properly loaded (js/htmx.min.js)? Maybe it's returning html content instead of js script code..

Comment: How could I check it? Have zero experisnce with javacript, therefor want to use HTMX

Comment: Can you please replace the included htmx script inclusion tag with the CDN version? and lmk what happenes then? (https://htmx.org/docs/#installing)

Comment: Solved. When downloading js file from here https://unpkg.com/browse/htmx.org@1.8.4/dist/ something else (some html page) was saved instead. Tried several time (right click -> save link as) by Edge and Firefox with same result. Download from different source work fine. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I never see an hx-post like your:

```
hx-post="cgi-bin/answer.cmd"
```

I think the problem stay there. Try with hx-get instead of hx-post.
I'm not sure if it is working, just try.

In any case don't give up to HTMX, it is working very well with the Django system templates, it is giving a new future to Django.

I typed a very basic demo and tutorial to understand the HTMX mechanism if you want to give a look:

[www.managepy.it demo and tutorial page](https://www.managepy.it/demo/)

In the same web page you will find another demo "Medium" where there is HTMX in action with pandas.